# Fetch records from two tables of database along with table name

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my database

1. dbo.Locations
2. dbo.Units

dbo.Units contains foreign key `Location_Id`

Now, I need to search a string which could be contains by any columns of above stated tables.

My requirement is that I need to fetch all columns along with "TABLE NAME".

Columns fetched successfully but how could I fetch table name whose column contains searchable text.

How could query for above problem made?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: `Select 'Units' as TableName, A.* From DBO.Units A`  but I don't get the question. An example (with sample data and expected results) would go a long way to improving my understanding.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the column name in the select to include the table name:

```
select table1.somecolumn as Table1_somecolumn
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a constant value, you can just select and name it:

```
select . . ., 'table name' as table_name
from . . .
```